# What does time delay in pinging signify?

Tags: router, ping

My internet connection was not working fine. So I ran a ping test. 
In command prompt I entered `ping 192.168.1.1 -t` (that is my default gateway).

Observing the response I noticed that the round trip delay kept on varying hugely.

`Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes 32 time=1ms TTL=254`

In place of the `1ms`, the round trip delay varied from `<1ms` to as high as `200ms` and never stabilized.

**What could be causing this? How can I rectify the problem? Is it a problem in my wireless router?**

Comment: its called 'latency' (the time lapse it takes for a signal to go from one place to another). Wifi is a notorious cause of latency. check here for some ideas on combatting wifi latency (note that many of these suggestions are not necessarilly for your circumstances; but the wifi router adjustments recommended are good): http://www.quantumclockwork.net/2011/05/06/reducing-wi-fi-latency/